# sizeof: Operator or Function?

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is sizeof an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-an-operator)

Why is `sizeof` supposed to be an **operator** in C, & not a **function**?

Its usage seems similar to that of a function call, as in `sizeof(int)`.

Is it supposed to be some kind of a pseudo-function?

Comment: Probably because `sizeof foo++` does not look like a function call, does not evaluate `foo++`, and `int` in `sizeof(int)` is not an expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's not a function; it's not possible to write a function that can take a type as an argument and return its size!  Note also that `sizeof` is implemented at compile-time, and that the parentheses aren't necessary if you're using it on a variable.

Answer (score 5):

A function call is evaluated at runtime. `sizeof` must be evaluated at compile time (though C99 introduces some exceptions to this, I believe)

Comment: Unless you have a VLA...

Answer (score 3):

A function in C cannot do what sizeof needs to do.

A function by definition is allocated space at runtime and can operate on data only.

While sizeof operates on datatypes as well, which are compiler specific. A function does not know how to interpret the datatype "int" and ask the compiler for its size, by design.

Before C99 sizeof was totally compile-time, but in the new standard, it can be used to get information at runtime as well, for variable-length arrays.

Answer (score 2):

function is something you can call at runtime. sizeof is only understood by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof has its effects at complite time not execution time.  You only need the ( ) when you enter a type such as sizeof(int) but if 'i' is of type int you could do sizeof i