# Allocate memory for an array inside a structure

Tags: c

I want to allocate memory to an array in a structure.

```
struct str
{
    int *num;

};

creat()
{
    str s = malloc(sizeof(str));
    s->num = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
}
```

But after execution of line `s->num = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));`, if I check, `sizeof(s->num)` is still the same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't cast the malloc.

Comment: You probably meant `str *s` instead of `str s`. Please consider editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

`s->num` is a pointer to integer and so its size will never change. You will have to keep track of the allocated block of memory that begins at `s->num` in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(s->num)` gives you the size of the pointer of type `int*` which won't change after your `malloc`. More precisely, `sizeof` is [not a function but an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-an-operator) and the value is given by your compiler. It's not a function that returns the size of the array allocated with `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `s->num` is not an array created dynamically but a pointer. Therefore it gives you the `sizeof` pointer.

To find the size of dynamically allocated array, a previous [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array/492410#492410) gives a clue as below,

1. As you're trying to allocate array of 5 integers, add 1 more integer to it and make it 6.
2. Hide the size in the first integer and return `ptr + 1` as the pointer to the array.
3. Now you can get the size at `*(ptr - 1)`, which is hidden first int.