# Using the sizeof() function correctly

Tags: c++, char, sizeof

Why is this syntax not correct?

```
 char* p = new char[dg.sizeof(Payload())];
```

I want to make a new variable that is a string the size of the Payload portion of dg... I don't understand how to do this? Thank you

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
 error: expected `]' before 'sizeof'
 error: expected ',' or ';' before 'sizeof'
```

Comment: What is `dg`? And `Payload`? I presume this is C?

Comment: unless dg has a sizeof function of its own, you are using it incorrectly

Comment: What is the return type of function Payload

Comment: Is `Payload` actually a function? We have just been told it's a "portion"

Comment: What are you trying to do? That's incorrect syntax. sizeof() returns a number, say,  8. dg.8 doesn't makes sense anyway

Comment: why is this tagged C? there's no `new` operator in C, and no methods in C either

Comment: Bad questions are going to lead to very bad answers.

Comment: the 'new' operator forces the code to be C++

Comment: the 'sizeof' is a compile time operator, not a runtime operator. so any activity at runtime is totally unrelated to the 'sizeof' operator.   The syntax is not correct for using the 'new' operator.  This 'may' be what your looking for:  'char* p = new char[strlen(dg.Payload)];'

Comment: @user3629249: "*'sizeof' is a compile time operator*" this is not exactly true, since C99 VLAs are around which be nature reveal their size on run-time. `sizeof` can by applied to a VLA.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator like `+` or `*`, but it operates at compile time. It takes one operand, either a typename in parens, or an expression (which need not be in parens). So if `Payload` is a member of structure `dg`, `sizeof dg.Payload` is the size of the function pointer member, and `sizeof dg.Payload()` is the size of `Payload()`'s return type.

Comment: [Why is sizeof considered as an operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714)

Answer (score 2):

sizeof is a c/c++ operator. It cannot be used as a class method.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char* p = new char[dg.sizeof(Payload())];
```

to

```
char* p = new char[sizeof(dg.Payload())];
```

Comment: I doubt `sizeof` is the right tool at all though. Looks like a function trying to return an array.

Comment: Note that this will return the sizeof() the return type of Payload, which may or may not be what the OP wants.  OP seems to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what sizeof is for.

Comment: We don't have enough context yet, but I'm already sure this answer is wrong ;)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Following up the "missing context" you mention the answer cannot be wrong, nor right ... ;-) - I however agree on that it might not solve the OP's issue ...