# Why does sizeof(my_arr)[0] compile and equal sizeof(my_arr[0])?

Tags: c, sizeof

Why does this code compile?

```
_Static uint32_t my_arr[2];
_Static_assert(sizeof(my_arr) == 8, "");
_Static_assert(sizeof(my_arr[0]) == 4, "");
_Static_assert(sizeof(my_arr)[0] == 4, "");
```

The first 2 asserts are obviously correct, but I would have expected the last line to fail, as my understanding is that `sizeof()` should evaluate to an integer literal, which can't be treated as an array. In other words, it would fail in the same way that the following line fails:

```
_Static_assert(4[0] == 4, "");
```

Interestingly, the following does indeed fail to compile (which should be doing the same thing, no?):

```
_Static_assert(*sizeof(my_arr) == 4, "");
```

> error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'long unsigned int') 
>   _Static_assert(*sizeof(my_arr) == 4, "");

If it matters, I'm using gcc 5.3.0

Comment: I suspect `( sizeof( my_arr ) )[ 0 ]` fails.

Comment: A recent duplicate has another variation on this syntax surprise: [Why does sizeof(x)++ compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61663807)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a function. It's a unary operator like `!` or `~`.

`sizeof(my_arr)[0]` parses as `sizeof (my_arr)[0]`, which is just `sizeof my_arr[0]` with redundant parentheses.

This is just like `!(my_arr)[0]` parses as `!(my_arr[0])`.

In general, postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators in C. `sizeof *a[i]++` parses as `sizeof (*((a[i])++))` (the postfix operators `[]` and `++` are applied to `a` first, then the prefix operators `*` and `sizeof`).

(This is the expression version of `sizeof`. There's also a type version, which takes a parenthesized type name: `sizeof (TYPE)`. In that case the parens would be required and part of the `sizeof` syntax.)

Comment: I definitely knew that sizeof was a unary operator and not a function, but totally forgot. Woops. Thanks for the detailed explanation. The fact that [] is higher precedence than * is interesting regardless.

Comment: @melpomene Interesting. I've never thought of `sizeof` being a unary operator.

Comment: Don't you mean `"... parses as sizeof (my_arr[0])"`? Just adding a space doesn't really change anything.

Comment: I would recommend `sizeof((my_array)[0])` instead

Comment: [Why is sizeof considered an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714)

Answer (score 46):

`sizeof` has two "versions": `sizeof(type name)` and `sizeof expression`. The former requires a pair of `()` around its argument. But the latter - the one with an expression as an argument - does not have `()` around its argument. Whatever `()` you use in the argument is seen as part of the argument expression, not part of `sizeof` syntax itself.

Since `my_arr` is known to the compiler as an object name, not a type name, your `sizeof(my_arr)[0]` is actually seen by the compiler as `sizeof` applied to an expression: `sizeof (my_arr)[0]`, where `(my_arr)[0]` is the argument expression. The `()` surrounding the array name is purely superfluous. The whole expression is interpreted as `sizeof my_arr[0]`. This is equivalent to your previous `sizeof(my_arr[0])`.

(This means, BTW, that your previous `sizeof(my_arr[0])` also contains a pair of superfluous `()`.)

It is a rather widespread misconception that `sizeof`'s syntax somehow requires a pair of `()` around its argument. This misconception is what misleads people's intuition when interpreting such expressions as `sizeof(my_arr)[0]`.

Comment: The first version exists so that you can check the size of an integer in general on the machine (from back when there weren't even 64-bit machines!), but `int` isn't a valid expression, so you can't use the second form with it.

Answer (score 27):

`[]` have a higher precendence than `sizeof`. So `sizeof(my_arr)[0]` is the same as `sizeof((my_arr)[0])`.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is a link to a precedence table.

Answer (score 8):

You're using the version of the `sizeof` operator that takes an expression as parameter. Unlike the one that takes a type, it *doesn't* require parentheses. Hence, the operand is simply `(my_arr)[0]`, with the parentheses being redundant.