# Why does sizeof(x)++ compile?

Tags: c, c99

I have run into the following code snippet:

```
int a = 3;
printf("%d", sizeof(a)++);
```

Apparently this will compile with GCC 9.3.0 and -std=c99.
While this does not compile:

```
printf("%d", sizeof(3)++);
```

GCC prints an error

> error: lvalue required as increment operand

Before I have compiled the first snippet I would have expected such an error.

The operand of the postfix ++ operator shall be an lvalue as of C99 standard

> The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall have qualified or unqualified real or pointer type and shall be a modifiable lvalue.

About the return value of the sizeof Operator (as expected):

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.
>
> The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type)
>   is size_t, defined in  (and other headers).

How is it possible the `sizeof(a)++` compiles? Is this undefined behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe the parentheses are confusing you.  You can also write it like this: `sizeof a++`.

Comment: It's the same as `sizeof (a++)`. `sizeof` is an operator and not a function. And it is lower precedence than `++`

Comment: Essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653406/why-does-sizeofmy-arr0-compile-and-equal-sizeofmy-arr0

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, and as any operator it has a precedence, which is in C lower than of the `++` operator. Therefore the construct `sizeof(a)++` is equivalent to `sizeof a++` which is in turn equivalent to `sizeof (a++)`. Here we have postincrement on `a` which is an lvalue so it is perfectly legal. If instead of `a` you have `3` which is not lvalue, the compilation will fail.

Comment: I swear... I lived a happier life before visiting this answer!