# The sizeof() function followed by square brackets

Tags: c++

I've seen an example showing as

```
int n = sizeof(0)["abcdefghij"];
cout<<n;
```

What does that thing in square brackets mean? I've read somewhere that `(0)["abc"]` is equivalent to `("abc")[0]`. Meaning the above expression is simply

```
n = sizeof("abcdefghij")[0];
```

i.e. the first element.

Comment: `"abcdefghij"` is just `const char [N]`, i.e. an array, so it's equivalent to `sizeof("abcdefghij"[0])` because [`sizeof` has higher precedence than `[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @phuclv - You had correct initially, pre-edit. It's not `sizeof("..."[0])`.

Comment: Naval, this example has a pretty poor practical value, if any at all. It may be a cool puzzle, but is not indicative of any real world construct.

Comment: sizeof is not a function: edit your title.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the precedence is wrong but the result is actually correct. I've checked it

Comment: @phuclv - I'm surprised. Though not by a lot. It's those darn parentheses. They only carry special meaning if they contain a typename.

Comment: another duplicate: [Why does `sizeof(my_arr)[0]` compile and equal `sizeof(my_arr[0])`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653406/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, [sizeof is **not** a function but an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714)

`sizeof(0)["abcdefghij"]` can be parsed as either

- `sizeof( (0)["abcdefghij"] )`, or
- `( sizeof(0) )["abcdefghij"]`

Since `sizeof` has [lower precedence than `[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the former will take place

`(0)["abcdefghij"]` is equivalent to [`"abcdefghij"[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/995714) which is just `'a'`, so the whole thing is the same as `sizeof('a')` which is 1 in C++

Demo on [GodBolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEADZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxd3JRUw2gYCZmICAONTTkVlTFU/ZNSCCLtHZzdFFLSMoOyFKuLrUujy1wBKRVQDYmQOAHIpAGZrZEMsAGpxQZ11euJMZiMp7HEABgBBNfXrAnGjZmsIHfHU4GRSceQEVPGAKlvTgDc2yYB2WQ3xr/H69BAULq7KY6YHjAgATw8mDw6AgPgAXphUFQIKs2uIAKyySSSZgOZBYKjABB4PhSSSYgAibQAdLRFpgIC9gaDySBJjjJtNQQikSi0Zjsbj8YTiaTyVSuSDpuMwAMMTpaHKph9Nq9KVs%2Bh1WCA%2Bhi%2BqRTH1VgbULqQTI5D8uj1MBzBpwDQRdSa2h0ANYgHE016DVaSbicVyvSScVYATl9vB1fW4BqNJtIZr6BoUIFWpGdxq1pDgsBgiABRg8eHYZAoEDQxdL5VGImAnDDGaopYIzjTEAcLoNDmsqXBusdpCrRi0BAA8rRWAPs6QsPtROxu3O8PN8o9MGnZ5gAB55Axt5c7ZTL1h4BzEft6LCDp3EPBGW8dGj0JhsDg8fheoT1lByORCOeaaQB0qAeIkW4ALTjoMqa5PkGgQOYNRZKQ5glFEMTBN4vh0Ch2GhH4GFlC4dTwYkhTVPomSCPEeQUQ0xEtKRlRFPhdSMU0mHlJwHQKDavRcNqur6oay7JjuAAcriQa43CXMIojjI2NKrKp4wQLghAkPa2TjHo1ZlvakgvBa2LSE63YdBASBViWZbkJQdk1i4Db%2BqQLasG2xAdl2s69vSxAzkOI5jpO07LvO9ZLrO%2BBrmoG5bomu77oes7HjGiZnheV4YP0Q4EPej59I6z50IwLBLp%2BAiDD%2Boh/paMiAQ4wFMkm4F%2BFBMFwQkfiaNo%2BHuOhXEkSAvAhLh/jUUE7gTYkTFYbwdEIUkDSDTkvV0JRjSRKNS1rdNphxJxu3MWNfECR%2Bwl6vG4m6lJMlyeMZzIMpamSBpWlEMQukXAZ9nOPagymf%2BMiWdm1m2aghnOI5lbQwDLh4MgyCSP6jbhh5rbtpQfmJgF/a3sO0OjvQ4UzomUWLv0lOrvReCJcuKXIAeNMGhlp7npeQXXvld4Pk%2BHnlW%2BVW8AI2SKWIoPyNlrWgR1dBdbBG304hyGHWY2gLTxng4Yk7G64R4QjWdZGbatbEa2bqsW2k2ssfUluBKhjt2ybWG8Z03SCZ7MaiQmpr3dJsnycjr2hjSnA0uGn34N9v36QjLm6SDjUWZmVkemNkg0q4jbcNwqyNhi3CDJGgzRrqcakI%2BGIZgHSa6qm6YZxDuYFjZICAh4B5w85ZYgLVmBxyQggvhV75cLwADul4eILfu3bOyZDIM4zT4QCDjA9IfPSjb00pI4OurmSDd73Fb9%2BUkhoSPLHjyLH4z3PC8iUviYr5IgwfRvBBbzvT06xKRUmpRMWYT6d3PgQPuScB7ZGHtpe%2BwtKpP1ILPZg88So5kXmJZeuohicHXpvbewcnph3GBHKO4Zj5ag6AgBYWAXBtRjNXWu9c7opkUN%2BcBtDSCeleK8Q%2BrhIwYkkt/V4klwz%2BleEIXUysG7JhoW6WRfQj64I/k3VuroOgbh8n1bgQA), [ideone](https://ideone.com/TTM4hy)

If you replace `sizeof(0)` with `sizeof(int)` then the same thing happens, but now `(int)["abcdefghij"]` is invalid so it should result in a compilation fail. [Most compilers report an error as expected that except ICC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEADZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxd3JRUw2gYCZmICAONTTkVlTFU/ZNSCCLtHZzdFFLSMoOyFKuLrUujy1wBKRVQDYmQOAHIpAGZrZEMsAGpxQZ11euJMZiMp7HEABgBBNfXrAnGjZmsINsmAdlkN8cvx%2BvQQFC7dqZ0n8YgfAC9MVCoIHbbxACsskkkmYDmQWCowAQeD4UkkgIAIscni8wAMATpaOipudNidEVs%2Bh1WCA%2BgC%2BqRTH1VpTUGTnjI5Ncuj1MJNJINOJSCGTaW0OgBrECSVYAOgBqwAnNwTtLBtxVoNVqsAZIhGTuJTqbTSPS%2BpSFCBVqReTTiaQ4LAYIh7kYPHh2GQKBA0PbHeVRiJgJxOCrSFRHQRnEaIA4%2BZSHNZUgBPMnc0huoxaAgAeVorDj5tIWH2onYEZzeHm%2BQAbpgjdnMAAPPIGYOFnbKQusPAOYixvRYeM84h4Iw9jo0ehMNgcHj8EVCb0oORyIRto2QDqoDyJSsAWlTg0NuXyGgg5hqWVI5hKURiwW8vjox6voT857KLjqe8ShWq%2BkygnieXfDSfFoX0qIo7zqACmgvcpOA6BRWV6LgSTJCkqULfVqwADlcDdXG4cYvVEcZfTFcVVleXBCBIDkuVIcY9HdJ1qMkY5GWBaQeQjDoICQN0HSdchKF4j0XB9VZ1UDVhg2IUNw2zKNaFjHtE1QIxk3odNM0LXNvQLbN8BLNRy0rXUazrBtsybUls1bdtOwwfoEwIPsBz6bkhzoRgWALCcBEGadRFnJkZAXBwlyOPU1z8Tdt13BI/E0bQwNPbRAMvbIQhvfwv1qTxr0SVLoJyOK6A/dJspPX99ySCDImfH8GiS%2BoigKl9YPg8ckPJbU0LJTDsNw8ZgGQZAiPFSRyPwIhiGo7I6JUvjnGowYWLnGQOPNLiePm4SBNdbanRAUtkA8DwAH1S04KVTskDDTurXCAyDENKFk3V5MU1zKSTFMNKzXVtPzfp/uLP88CMwtTOQesgcpSyWzbDtiBjLsHN7ftBwDDzR283gBF4YQAokIL5BssKV0iuhK1i0GDyPcqzBSyC6vSvK/CSjL8qZoCfzfAoGvp19iuq5qubSkDP0CCqauaNK2u6BCYI1LrUOzdCBqMBQjvGC6pTFG6Jso6ahlm%2BiFqNzluBW4n1v5S0toY5xdqEg68GG0VJF9KVHsk56w0Ld6kaU771IzP7KQB4BdOBgywYrCHayh8zdTh6yEbs7tPtNZyMeHTyxy4XHBAJsRVpJxd4HJ9cyS3Hcipp0xD0SgXkssUXCo5tnm478I2%2BAyr/1A5v%2B75kXau58DB8l%2BrR5l6C5bZRClZQnU6V6rCcLw12Ro9sVODFKUDammbaNN4SZqttibeJIUQG4SQxVcX1uEVX0AW4QYpROBUla1UgB24XWUogHAJASAlWup9SGmNKaTilobTcRAA8Dw9Ynb7XKH5TAk0SCCFztjccvAADuHYPAYyssvHqAxOSDHGAQwgCBxh9Q3oNYao09ZX02og%2BsyCCCoIdi4dUmDDY4Kxl5fBpAiHMBIZ9Tq5DVZkiGONWhBB6GMIGgRYARE96kXYXbThBBuG8LNmYLBwFcGiILuI4hpDkLdTkZQrkNC6EMPXgNLe4wd57ylDohBSCUEumduUXggiprCJHOYicEipFuSXrYiB8iLaOOUQw9WmsRo6z1hhdhHQEALCwC4cKVlf7/0AaA0pQDwGrwNIoEAfkzT8hvicXWADVSSClKsVwAIpSuCAScJWtcV56jJFkpWkhYmVOGeWaS8VuBAA%3D%3D) so it looks like that's an [ICC bug](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Bug-regarding-precedence-of-sizeof/m-p/1254415) which chooses `(sizeof(int))["abcdefghij"]` over `sizeof((int)["abcdefghij"])` just because the latter is invalid

Related: [Why does sizeof(my_arr)[0] compile and equal sizeof(my_arr[0])?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653406/995714)

Comment: It would be an interesting exercise to `s/0/int` and discuss the difference.