# Why does sizeof(*"327") return 1 instead of 8 on a 64 bit system?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
 printf("%lu \n", sizeof(*"327"));
```

I always thought that size of a pointer was 8 bytes on a 64 bit system but this call keeps returning 1.  Can someone provide an explanation?

Comment: `sizeof(*"327")` is `sizeof(char)` since `*` dereferences the first char of your literal string. just try `sizeof(char *)`

Comment: String literals are arrays of characters, and you get a pointer to its first character (type `char *`). Now, when you dereference a pointer to `char` what do you get?

Comment: I also recommend you read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), because `"%lu"` is the wrong format for `sizeof` arguments.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for the star?   Why did you put the star in?

Comment: Sidenote: `sizeof` is no function that could be called.

Comment: [you can't call `sizeof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714)

Comment: You may have been thinking of `sizeof(&"327")`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.  The page you referenced does not contain the 'special' formats for pointers, sizeof(), etc.

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile time operator, similar to `return` as it is not a function

Comment: @user3629249 Yes it does. Scroll down a little bit, look at the large table. You will find the `p` conversion specifier for pointers, and for `size_t` you will find it in the `z` argument-type sub-column.

Comment: @user3629249 `sizeof` is an *operator* but `return` is a *statement*. The `sizeof` operator is *mostly* compile-time, but can't be for e.g. [variable-length arrays]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). And the `return` *statement* is all run-time, since it can't really be executed at compile-time, especially if it's supposed to return a computed value.

Answer (score 61):

Putting `*` before a string literal will dereference the literal (as string literal are array of characters and will decay to pointer to its first element in this context). The statement

```
printf("%zu \n", sizeof(*"327"));
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%zu \n", sizeof("327"[0]));
```

`"327"[0]` will give the first element of the string literal `"327"`, which is character `'3'`. Type of `"327"`, after decay, is of `char *` and after dereferencing it will give a value of type `char` and ultimately `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: I haven't programmed in C for about 10 years, but when did sizeof('3') become sizeof(int)? A character literal was always one byte. Have they finally defaulted to using wide characters for Unicode support?

Comment: @dwilliss; In C, `'3'` an integer constant.  As per C standard an integer character constant has type `int`.

Comment: @haccks so is `'3'` really a different type than '`m`'?! I find it hard to believe so I must be misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Wilson; No. `'3'` has same type as of `'m'`: both are character constants. But I don't know why standard used "integer character constant".  *"An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer."*--C11:6.4.4.4(p10).

Comment: @Wilson You misunderstand. All character constants have always been of type `int` in C. Only in C++ is `'3'` (or `'m'`) of type `char`. Don't believe it? `int main() { printf("%zu\n", sizeof 'm');}`

Comment: I wonder if this is something that changed (or was clarified by) C99. I also remember compiler flags to make chars the same as wchar_t.  But that was in the 80's.

Comment: @dwilliss [it has always been an `int` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2172943/995714)

Comment: It's not really dereferencing to `'3'` (i.e. a character literal). It is dereferencing a string literal (`char*`) to the first element which will be a `char` and hence a single byte (`*(char*) = (char)`). It just happens that the value of the dereferenced string literal is `(char)'3'` because that is the first character in the string.

Comment: @dwilliss `sizeof('3')` has always been the same as  `sizeof(int)`. Likewise, `sizeof(*"3")` has always been the same as `sizeof(char)`. As illogical as it may sound, a character literal is not of type `char`. In fact, *all* literals in C are at least the size of `int`. To get something of type `char`, you need an expression with something other than a literal in it.

Comment: @MarkReed the compound literal `(char){'3'}` has size 1

Comment: I would count a typecast as "something other than a literal", but fair enough. :)

Comment: @MarkReed; Interestingly, `(char)` in `(char){'3'}` is not a typecast! He said "compound literal" :)

Comment: No, it absolutely is. You can replace the `char` inside the parentheses with `short`,`int`, or `long` and get the corresponding size.

Comment: @MarkReed; *"A postﬁx expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list."* - n1570: 6.5.2.5/3. Try to compile these to separately to see the difference: `printf("%d\n", ++(char){'3'});` and `printf("%d\n", ++(char)('3'));`. You will see the difference between a cast operator and  compound literal.

Answer (score 18):

The statement:

```
printf("%lu \n", sizeof(*"327"));
```

actually prints the size of a `char`, as using `*` dereferences the first character of string `327`. Change it to:

```
char* str = "327";
printf("%zu \n", sizeof(str));
```

Note that we need to use `%zu` here, instead of `%lu`, because [we are printing a `size_t` value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087).

Answer (score 4):

The string literal is an anonymous, static array of chars, which decays to a pointer to its first character -- that is, a pointer value of type `char *`.

As a result expression like `*"abc"` is equivalent to `*someArrayOfCharName`, which in turn is equivalent to `*&firstCharInArray` which results in `firstCharInArray`. And `sizeof(firstCharInArray)` is `sizeof(char)` which is `1`.

Comment: *Almost* correct. Even while the array is read-only (can't be modified), it's not `const`. So it decays to a plain non-const `char *`. This is one of the things that makes C and C++ different.

Comment: Technically it doesn't decay unless used in a decay context . This is why `sizeof "abcd"` is 5. Applying the dereference operator is a decay context of course

Answer (score 0):

Good answer by [haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705356/6935629).

Also, the behaviour of your code is **undefined**, because you have used the wrong format specifier.

So, use `%zu` instead of `%lu` because `sizeof()` returns `size_t` and `size_t` is `unsigned`.

**C11 Standard: §7.21.6.1: Paragraph 9:**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.225) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: While this is true, this should be a comment. There is no UB in case `size_t` is of smaller or equal size as `unsigned long`.

Comment: @Lundin No matter what type `size_t` is, either it doesn't promote, or it promotes to `signed int`/`unsigned int`, so the only way you'll get an `unsigned long` passed to `printf` is if `size_t` already is an `unsigned long`. I don't see how you can say, then, that the behaviour is defined if `size_t` is anything else.

Comment: @hvd Fine, but this isn't a real-world problem and it doesn't answer the question. In the real world, either both long and size_t are of the same size and there is no problem. Or long is 32 bit while size_t is larger, in which case you might end up reading part of the size_t but you don't invoke any UB by that.

Comment: @Lundin "but you don't invoke any UB by that" -- This answer already explains why you're wrong. The standard explicitly states the behaviour is undefined, and it *has* to be undefined, because there's no sensible way to define it that works for all calling conventions. Agreed that it doesn't answer the question, but it's entirely accurate and would have been worth posting as a comment.

Comment: It *might be* undefined;  it's a common implementation choice for `size_t` to be a typedef for `unsigned long`