# Format specifier for sizeof() operator

Tags: c, sizeof, format-specifiers

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705515/6935629) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705264/why-does-sizeof327-return-1-instead-of-8-on-a-64-bit-system), If you use wrong format specifier then the behaviour of your code is undefined.

In that question, OP used `%lu` format specifier for `sizeof` operator.

```
printf("%lu \n", sizeof(*"327"));
```

But, I got some comments, `%lu` not UB for that code.

So, Is it true for `sizeof(*"327")`?

Comment: The discussion in the comments seemed to be about whether `size_t` is `typedef`d to be `unsigned long` or not, so whether it invokes UB or not seems to depend on the compiler?

Comment: Well, I think the bigger problem is, "Why would you ever do that."  There's nothing really "wrong" with the format specifier, though that may not be the specifier that will properly display the value..  That simply means that it will be displayed incorrectly, not that it is necessarily UB.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Actually sir I know correct format specifier of sizeof.  And also I mentioned in my answer , but some peoples commented my answer, it's not UB?? My answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705515/6935629

Comment: @rsp, reopened. But this was not at all clear from your question, please improve it. The contents should not be hidden behind links.

Comment: Wait a sec, you did not find any dupe of this? That's a little surprising...

Comment: @SouravGhosh, as rsp remarked I search for the wrong fact for the duplicate. But you are right for the question "is the behavior of this undefined" there should be one, too.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, so what you found is again wrong, it does not answer the question that rsp wanted to ask.

Comment: @JensGustedt sir, I guess I understand the question sir, but the point is, as already known by RSP, that the correct specifier is `%zu` and anything else is UB. If any specific info is to be added for any other environment, then the question has to be updated with that info, don't you recommend that?

Comment: @rsp If it feels any better, you are theoretically correct and if you stick to that, you'll be writing much better and portable and conforming code, just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator returns a type of `size_t`.  The proper format specifier for that type is `%zu`.

If you use `%lu` to print a `size_t`, it may or may not work, depending on whether or not `size_t` is larger than a `long`.  If `size_t` is larger, you have undefined behavior, if not the behavior is well defined.  Of course, you can't really know for sure.

Better to use the proper format specifier specific to that type.

Answer (score 1):

Unix systems (nearly?) always have `size_t == unsigned long == uintptr_t`, and there is a *lot* of code that relies on the fact.

The only system in common use that's different is 64-bit Windows, where `unsigned long` is 32-bit but `size_t` and `uintptr_t` are 64-bit.

(Does windows even have a support for `%zu` in `printf`?)

Comment: "*Does windows even have a support `%zu` ...*" that not a question of the OS, but of the compiler. VC hasn't, others have.