# I do not get the right size of a string if I pass the string to an other function in c

Tags: c

I cannot seem to find the right syntax to find get the size of a string in c, after the string is passed to a function.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnS0n.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void testfunction(char *test);

int main()
{
char test[20];

printf("%lu\n", sizeof(test));
testfunction(test);

}

void testfunction(char *test)
{
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(test));
}
```

If I run this code, the first time it prints the correct value of 20, but the second time it prints 8. I know it probably has something to do with a false pointer syntax because the 8 value is the number of bytes in which the pointer address is stored. But I just cannot figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Please don't post code as (just an) image. Please edit your post to address this deficiency.

Comment: As an aside, `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, and the correct format specifier for a `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: @John3136, No. `strlen` would not be useful here.

Comment: Using `strlen` with an uninitialized char array would result in UB.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). [Correct format specifier for `sizeof`: %zu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46729692/995714)

Comment: Please do not forget: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

`main`'s `test` is an array of 20 `char`. You are getting the size of that array.

`testFunction`'s `test` is a `char *`. You are getting the size of that pointer.

Those two sizes are unrelated.

It's impossible to pass an array to a function. So you'll need to pass the size of the array as an argument if it's needed in the function.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't get the size of an array after it has been passed to a function -- the function has no knowledge of it unless the caller passes that info to the function as a parameter or some other means.  Your original `testfunction()` is only reporting the size of the `test` pointer -- not the array size, because that info is not available to `testfunction()` .

You can however, get the string length of an array which contains a string such as in this example.  In this code, we've modified `test` buffer to hold a string 19 characters long, and with the terminating NUL we consume all the buffer memory of 20 chars.

`testfunction()` is also modified to discover the string length and report it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testfunction(char test[20]);

int main()
{
char test[20]="String is 19 chars.";

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(test));
    testfunction(test);
}

void testfunction(char test[20])
{
    char *ptr = test;
    while(*ptr++);

    printf("%lu\n", (int)(ptr-test));
}
```

Output:

```
20
20
```

Runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8MbKbxjvE).