# Is sizeof a function or an operator?

Tags: c, operators, sizeof, function-call

**Why do we say `sizeof(variable)` is an operator, not a function?**

It looks like a function call and when I am thinking about the meaning of operator, it appears to me something like `+` or `-` or `*` and so on

Comment: Because `sizeof` (all one word) is an operator, not a function, for example `sizeof myvar`. It needs parentheses for a *type*.

Comment: You only need parens if what follows is an expression.

Comment: You can write `x = +(y)`.  The parentheses do not make `+` a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is sizeof considered an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-an-operator)

Answer (score 8):

It's an operator, and you don't need to use brackets, except "*when the operand is a type name, it must be enclosed in parentheses*". This is a syntax restriction, but should not be confused with a function call.

See the last example below from the GNU [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-sizeof-Operator):

```
size_t a = sizeof(int);
size_t b = sizeof(float);
size_t c = sizeof(5);
size_t d = sizeof(5.143);
size_t e = sizeof a;
```

Without parentheses for a type name, you may see an error like this, with the gcc compiler:

```
test.c:7:20: error: expected expression before ‘int’
    7 |  size_t s = sizeof int;
      |                    ^~~
```

But doing `sizeof 12` or `sizeof a` is fine.

Answer (score 5):

It's an *operator* because it doesn't take arguments like a function does. It operates at the syntax level.

`f(int)` is not a valid function call, but `sizeof(int)` is a valid use of `sizeof`.

It can also operate on variables or types, it's quite flexible by design, which is something an operator can do as it's baked deep into the C syntax.

More details [can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).

Comment: `sizeof int` is not specified by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is that a C++-ism?

Comment: Are you thinking of `sizeof expression` rather than `sizeof (type)`?

Answer (score 3):

As the grammar indicates:

```
unary-expression:
  postfix-expression
  ++ unary-expression
  -- unary-expression
  unary-operator cast-expression
  sizeof unary-expression
  sizeof (type-name)
  _Alignof (type-name)

unary-operator: one of
  & * + - ~ !
```

it's an operator that not only does not require parentheses when taking an `unary-expression` argument, but it behaves differently with parentheses than a function call would.

Consider that given `_Static_assert(sizeof(0)==4,"");`, the following holds:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(0)==4,"");
int takeIntGive4(int X){ (void)X; return 4; }

#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    assert(sizeof(0)["foobar"] == 1  && 1 == sizeof(char)); //if sizeof were more function-like you'd get 'a'
    assert(takeIntGive4(0)["foobar"] == 'a');
}
```

In other words, even though `sizeof(0) == takeIntGive4(0)` is true on this platform, you can't always just replace `takeIntGive4(0)` with `sizeof(0)` because `sizeof` has a lower precedence than a function call and `sizeof(0)["foobar"]` will be interpreted as `sizeof( (0)["foobar"] )`, not `(sizeof(0))["foobar"]` like it would  be if `sizeof()` were a function.

You can make sizeof function-like, by wrapping it in a macro that parenthesizes it:

```
#define SIZEOF(X) (sizeof(X))
```

but keep in mind that `sizeof` also additionally returns integer constant expressions (except when used with variable-length arrays (VLAs)), which you can use in `case` labels, bitfield sizes, and array sizes and which function call expressions are incapable of returning.

Answer (score 2):

It is an operator because it is built into the language. Just like `+` or `<` it is included in the language grammar. Because of this the `sizeof` operator can be evaluated when a program is compiled, unlike a user-defined function. For example we can define a function macro which returns the length of a (non-variable length) array:

```
#define LENGTH(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0])
```

The length expression is calculated when the program is compiled. At run-time the length of an array is not available (unless you store it in a separate variable).

Comment: `sizeof` is generally not evaluated during compilation for variable length arrays.

Comment: And most uses of arithmetic and relational operators cannot be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the information. I have update the answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, the operands must be constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It's an operator that's evaluated at compile-time.

In fact, it only requires the function-like syntax `sizeof(T)` when `T` is a type and not an instance of a type.

So, for example, if you have a variable `int x`, `sizeof x` is permissible; but `sizeof(int)` is required for the type `int`.

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile time constant (technically: necessarily qualifies as an integer constant) only if its operand does not have variable length array type.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is an **operator**.  It is listed among the list of unary operators in section 6.5.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.5.3  Unary operators**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> unary-expression:
>   postfix-expression
>   ++ unary-expression
>   -- unary-expression
>   unary-operator cast-expression
>   sizeof unary-expression
>   sizeof (type-name)
>   _Alignof (type-name)
>
> unary-operator: one of
>   & * + - ~ !
> ```

As shown above it has two forms.  The first form is `sizeof` followed by an expression.  Note that in this form parenthesis are not required, unlike in a function call where they are.  The second form is `sizeof` followed by a type name in parenthesis.  Only the second form requires parenthesis, and a function cannot be passed a type name.

It is further referred to as an operator in section 6.5.3.4:

> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
>
> ...
>
> *2* The `sizeof` operator  yields  the  size  (in  bytes)  of  its  operand,  which  may  be  an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.  The size is determined from the type of the operand.  The result is an integer.  If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant

Answer (score 0):

> Is sizeof a function or an operator?
> Why we said sizeof(variable) is operator not function?

In addition to what other have answered, code can take the address of a function, but not the address of `sizeof`.  Much like can cannot take the address of `=` or `*`.

```
size_t (*f1)() = strlen;
size_t (*f2)() = sizeof;
//                     ^ error: expected expression before ';' token
```

---

With objects, the `()` are not needed with `sizeof`, unlike a function call.

```
char array[42];
size_t n1 = sizeof array;
size_t n2 = strlen(array) + 1;
```

---

`sizeof` can be used with *types*, not so with a function call.

```
size_t sz1 = sizeof(double);
size_t sz2 = printf(double);
//                  ^ error: expected expression before 'double'
```