# How to write custom sizeof() function in c?

Tags: c, sizeof

I want to implement an alternative custom function for c sizeof() operator. I got below definition from internet and its working pretty good.

```
#define my_sizeof(type) (char *)(&type+1)-(char*)(&type)
```

But instead of preprocessor (#define macro) function i would like to implement it as a separate function as below. **Can somebody help me to complete the definition of sizeof_custom()?**

**Note:** Why I wanted to implement in this way is to understand cause of the difficulties I faced while I try to implement it with void pointers and find the diff (I understand void pointer does not allow arithmetic operations, but then how I can build this function?). Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

return_type sizeof_custom ( arg )
{
....
....
// return the size of the variable
}

void main() 
{
int a;  // It can be int, float, char,....
printf("size = %d", sizeof_custom(a));
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a function, it's an expression that's part of the language (and therefore treated special by the compiler)

Comment: @UnholySheep it is an operator.

Comment: Why, why, why, ....? You can do it but only because there is all ready a `sizeof` hidden in the compiler

Comment: [Why is sizeof considered an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714). Many things can't be done via code and has to rely on compiler features or builtins

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to implement `sizeof` operator using other language features. It is part of the language and has to be implemented by the compiler. Most importantly because:

- array types do not decay to pointers
- expression in `sizeof` is not evaluated
- variable-length arrays are handled specially

Comment: What is VLA? I've been using C for many years and never heard of that?

Comment: @OmarL Variable Length Array. As in `int sz = user_input(); int arr[sz];`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays

Comment: @OmarL Don't worry ... VLA is something you never want to use anyway.

Comment: Also @4386427 VLAs are optional since C11 ... best change to C99 :-)

Comment: @4386427 there are some rare cases when I know for sure that the size cannot be big enough to cause an issue, so I feel it is safe to use VLAs. But I suppose since VLAs are optional as of C11, you might want to use `alloca` for more portability in that case anyways...