# Explain the output. Why is 'a' not updated to 1?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, a = 0;
    x = sizeof(a++) ? printf("Geeks for Geeks\n") : 0;
    printf("Value of x:%d\n", x);
    printf("Value of a:%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code.

I expected the output to be:

Value of x:16 
Value of a:1

But the output on GCC compiler is:

Value of x:16 
Value of a:0

Comment: `sizeof` *usually* does not evaluate its arguments; it just needs the type, not the value. `sizeof (printf("Hello World\n"))` is the same as `sizeof (int)` and absolutely nothing gets printed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/

Comment: TIL the "usual arithmetic conversions", unlike default argument promotions, do not promote `floats` to `doubles`! https://ideone.com/vIv9pP and C23-6.3.1.8 -- I never use `floats` anyways :-)

Comment: For bonus points, explain why `x = sizeof(typeof(int[a++])) ? ...` gives `x:0 a:1`  :)

Comment: @Lundin [I got nasal demons](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p5)  ;-)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's because <s>sizeof is actually an operator</s>. This means that the operand is not evaluated at runtime. You can find a better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-an-operator).

Edit: sizeof is a compile-time operator that takes the type of a variable. This means that it will not evaluate what is passed to it.

Comment: Hmmm *kinda* ... it being an operator is irrelevant (though true, of course).

Comment: `+` is also an operator but it does evaluate its operands.

Comment: @interjay operator+ is a runtime operator, sizeof is a compile time operator that does not evaluate the value of it's operands only their types

Comment: _"sizeof is a compile-time operator"_ -- that isn't what the Standard says; it says explicitly that `sizeof` doesn't evaluate it's operand (unless the operand is a VLA type). It is wrong to say that the operand is not evaluated because `sizeof` is compile time; it is not evaluated because the Standard says so. C is not required to be compiled (and there are C interpreters) so compile time `sizeof` is an implementation detail. _"that takes the type of a variable"_ -- `sizeof` takes either an expression or a parenthesized type as its operand.

Comment: Strike outs and "edit" [do not belong in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011) (that is what the revision history and edit summaries are for). Thanks in advance.